# Html in a script tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to manage my little nav in 1file(which I want to do with every nav I've on my website to make website management easier). I've put an ID tag on the body on each webpage. If you guys can help me with this/show me a better way I would highly appriciate it :D!

```
                                    <script>
                                    if (document.getElementById("Games"))
                                    {

                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="Games.php">Games</a>
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <li><a href="Books.php">Books</a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="Movies.php">Movies</a></li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>

                                }
                                    else if(document.getElementById("Webdesign"))
                                    {

                                        <ul>
                                                <li><a href="Games.php">Webdesign</a>
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <li><a href="Books.php">Books</a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="Movies.php">Movies</a></li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </li>
                                        </ul>

                                    }
                                    else(document.getElementById("Cloudspace"))
                                    {

                                        <ul>
                                                <li><a href="Games.php">Books</a>
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <li><a href="Books.php">Games</a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="Movies.php">Movies</a></li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </li>
                                        </ul>

                                    }
                                    </script>
```

EDIT: I've a dropdown menu like this: http://www.glovizion.eu/index.php and I want if I click on the page books to see Books as the top of the dropdown menu
but still want it to be a 1file header so it's easy managable for editing without the need to change it on every page.

Comment: Can you be clear on what you are trying to achieve. Nvm, I got it now.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write

Comment: It's either JavaScript or it's HTML, it can't be both.  You could perhaps use `document.write()` to write HTML strings, but that's a little sloppy.  What you're probably looking to do is assign `id`s to your elements and style them to not be visible, then in your JavaScript code determine which one should be visible and change its styling.

Comment: Why don;t you just have the HTML there and show/hide elements?

Comment: It was just to have different versions of my dropdown menu one where for example games is shown and when you hover it you get the other 2 choices(books, movies) if i'm on the gaming page when I'm on the books page I only want to see books and when I hover it I would have the other 2 choices games and movies. Why do I've -2 I get my code is bad but I'm here to get help right xD...

Answer (score 1):

Create a JavaScript function to find your link with ID 'myLink'

Set the innerHTML of your link to body's ID

Call your JavaScript function on body's onload event

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function changeNavCaption() {
                var link = document.getElementByID('myLink');
                var bodyID = document.body.id;

                link.innerHTML = bodyID;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body id="Books" onload="changeNavCaption()">
        <ul>
            <li><a id="myLink" href="Games.php">Books</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="Books.php">Books</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Movies.php">Movies</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
         </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand it 100% but I will do some extra research on it ^_^!

Comment: What part of it you don't understand

Comment: link = search for the element with the id('myLink') bodyid = is just the id of the body like <body id="Books"> link.innerHTML is the html inside the link so the anchor will be the name of the body id? I don't know if I understand it or not but it didn't work while I tried it... I think I need some if structure or somthing to show the right ul li a on criteria like body id so I can manage the same dropdown menu in 1file for all pages with a <? require('page.php');?>  I'm a bit confused and don't really know where to start looking anymore...

Comment: You wanted your link to display the current page's ID right. My bad on forgetting to set the ID as an example. Check again.

Comment: Yeaaa and I don't really need a href on the first link because it's the page itself  but the problem with this solution would be if i'm on the page books it will show the first anchor as Books while seeing in the dropdown menu books also as a clickable page it's really a stupid detail so I will probaly use the php method I found it's more code but for the moment is the best solution I found

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind found the solution on my own answer and it's super simpel maybe a bit outdated I don't know if there are better solutions:

http://v1.jontangerine.com/log/2008/02/designer-php-a-dynamic-menu-with-if-and-else